# Does a comment really need to be about women in general, to be "misogynistic"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Basically, the argument I'm seeing being made is that Unnamed-Person's ugly comments are not "misogynistic" because [Wikipedia defines "misogyny" as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misogyny):

> hatred of, contempt for, or prejudice against women or girls

because:

> women without article here means "women" in general, not "some women"

Basically the argument is that because the many comments are not being made about women in general, just some specific subset of women and sometimes very specific women, they are not "misogynistic".

To me this seems like [ambiguity fallacy](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/ambiguity) and maybe [special pleading fallacy](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/special-pleading) (because they appear to be trying to twist the definition of the words in the definition to make what they said technically correct), but it made me wonder, does any of this argument make sense? Is "misogynistic" really not applicable to comments that aren't made about women in general?

Comment: P.S. This is my first time posting and I don't really frequent these parts of Stack Exchange. Please let me know if I can improve my question in any way.

Comment: Mysogynistic    refers to women as a gender, what do you mean by a subset of women?

Comment: This question (and my comment) may be too opinion based, but I think that a comment does not have to apply to all women to be misogynistic. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misogynist is more general in its definition: "A person who dislikes, despises, or is strongly prejudiced against women."
A comment can certainly display those attributes without needing to apply to all women. That is, the comment doesn't have to be something like "women are ___" or "I sure do hate and disrespect women" to be misogynistic.

Comment: It really depends on what sort of comments they are that you make about specific women/groups of women. If I say *I can't abide Theresa May, and I think she is a bad Prime Minister* that could not be taken as misogynist, since I could equally have said something similar about her predecessor - a man. However if I say *Theresa May does not have the bearing and authority needed, the job requires a man*, that is clearly misogynistic as it carries the implication that men are more capable than women in high office.

Comment: @JOSH - Examples of subsets of women: housewives, coeds, female wrestlers, working mothers.

Comment: @aparente001 - so the question is: if I hate working mothers but not other women am I  mysogynistic?

Comment: You need to give an example sentence where there is the ambiguity problem and one where it is not ambiguous.

Comment: @Mitch The "ambiguity fallacy" part was in reference to trying to manipulate the definition of words in the definition, to massage a definition that didn't include what they said, to try to make what they said *technically* correct. Specifically '"women without article here means "women" in general, not "some women"'. The ugly commentary itself was completely unambiguous.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara OK, but in your OP you need to give the first statement that is ambiguous so that it is clear (without having to scan all the comments)

Comment: @JOSH - I guess it depends on why you hate them.  If you have painful memories of separation anxiety from when you were 3 or 4 I suppose that might be a rationale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, of course not.

Don’t hyperfocus on some random crowd-sourced Internet “definition” here. Don’t get hung up on the letter of the would-be law here either.

Misogyny is bigotry against women — *any* bigotry against *any* women whenever the ultimate source of the bigot’s prejudged dismissal, contempt, dislike, derision, hatred for that woman is because she’s a woman.

It doesn’t matter whether the bigot doesn’t hate every possible woman. It could even be just a single woman because the hatred derives from *what* not *who* she is.  And it most definitely doesn’t matter if “some of his best friends” are women.

Bigotry is judging someone for what they are not for who they are, and misogyny is nothing else than bigotry against women.

Go back and swap in any other disenfranchised group in the language above about bigotry and nothing changes: race, religion, hair or eye or skin color, national origin, disability, or anything else you can think of that people hate other people because of.

It’s all the same thing, and bigotry is what it is.

Comment: May I suggest a comma or something in that "from what not who she is" bit? I actually had to read it a few times to make out it wasn't a typo.

Comment: Seems like it reads cleanly as is without a comma — or even a dash — to slow it down. :)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - tchrist, I proposed italics although I would have preferred dashes, or commas. See if you can live with this edit.